# SignalR listener not getting invoked in React Native

Tags: react-native, signalr, signalr-hub

I am building a mobile app in React Native for a backend written in .NET. The backend has implemented a realtime messaging service using SignalR Hubs. I am using the package `react-native-signalr`. The connection is getting established, and I can send message to SignalR hub by calling `proxy.invoke`. The problem is in reception of message. I tried with `proxy.on` but nothing happens.

```
componentDidMount(){
  const { access_token } = this.props;

  // Setup connection to signalr hub.
  const hubUrl = `${API_URL}/signalr`;
  const connection = signalr.hubConnection(hubUrl);
  const proxy = connection.createHubProxy('MessagesHub', {queryParams: { token: access_token }});

  // Start connection
  connection.start();

  // Trying to receive message from SignalR Hub
  proxy.on('messageReceived', message => {
    console.log(message);
  })
  proxy.on('sendPrivateMessage', message => {
    console.log(message);
  })
  proxy.on('sentPrivateMessage', message => {
    console.log(message);
  })
}
```

Comment: can you navigate to your huburl/signalr/negotiate?

Comment: @xSkrappy response of signalr/negotiate

`{"Url":"/API/signalr","ConnectionToken":"zel8uzcmSs6Tenu+jpDcYNRcj/8KeTlV+00LQIzeFdgD/TdjeXXeyHRLvknybDJ0ruKDKttcipS6l2wrsawUEwscjMVENEFMMdCbtO4MrFrYjIJrePwxGs9BPWDBSI56QphwBgI1JeVSysr5HSw7GQ==","ConnectionId":"a166558f-0046-450d-b7d3-4ff25a57a636","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":false,"ProtocolVersion":"1.2","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0}`

Comment: Try to put the proxy.on above connection.start()

Comment: @xSkrappy I tried. But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

when you register a listener with your_proxy.on function ,you must define a function with required parameters and bind it on constructor and then pass it to your_proxy.on function ,see bellow:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.messageReceived=this.messageReceived.bind(this);   // <========== **Important**
        this.sendPrivateMessage=this.sendPrivateMessage.bind(this);   // <========== **Important**
        this.sentPrivateMessage=this.sentPrivateMessage.bind(this);   // <========== **Important**
    }

messageReceived(message ){
             console.log(message);
    }
    sendPrivateMessage(message ){
             console.log(message);
    }
    sentPrivateMessage(message ){
             console.log(message);
    }
componentDidMount(){
  const { access_token } = this.props;

  // Setup connection to signalr hub.
  const hubUrl = `${API_URL}/signalr`;
  const connection = signalr.hubConnection(hubUrl);
  const proxy = connection.createHubProxy('MessagesHub', {queryParams: { token: access_token }});

// Trying to receive message from SignalR Hub
  proxy.on('messageReceived', this.messageReceived);
  proxy.on('sendPrivateMessage', this.sendPrivateMessage);
  proxy.on('sentPrivateMessage', this.sentPrivateMessage);

  // Start connection
  connection.start();
}
```